# getting error while creating build in angular 5

Tags: node.js, npm, angular5

1. **i am trying to creating a build and getting below error**

   11 silly lifecycle corporate-solutions@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 139  signal: null

   11 silly lifecycle corporate-solutions@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 139  signal: null

   12 info lifecycle corporate-solutions@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script

   **13 verbose stack Exit status 139**

   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)

   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

   13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)

   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)

   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

   13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)

   13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)

   13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

> also sometimes getting same error while start the Server

1. **npm version v5.7.1**
2. **node version v8.9.3**
3. **OS : ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

> below is my package.json

```
{
"name": "corporate-solutions",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --ec true --port 4203 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=5300 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod",
    "win-build": "node --max_old_space_size=5300 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-notify": "node --max_old_space_size=5300 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod && echo 'message: Build Completed' | zenity --notification --listen",
    "build-push": "node --max_old_space_size=5300 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod && ./distupload.sh",
    "gitbuild": "ng build --prod --base /start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/master/dist/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:dynamic": "npm run build:dynamic && npm run serve:dynamic",
    "start:static": "npm run build:static && npm run serve:static",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "build:static": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server && npm run generate:static",
    "build:dynamic": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "generate:static": "cd dist && node prerender",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:static": "cd dist/browser && http-server",
    "serve:dynamic": "node dist/server"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.0-9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@ngx-cache/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^0.6.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.24.1",
    "angular-fontawesome": "^1.0.0",
    "angular-star-rating": "^3.0.8",
    "angular2-csv": "0.2.5",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "2.5.0",
    "angular2piwik": "^0.1.5-beta",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "calendar-utils": "^0.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.10",
    "grapesjs": "^0.14.10",
    "grapesjs-preset-webpage": "^0.1.9",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.2",
    "howler": "^2.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.16",
    "ng-click-outside": "^3.2.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^3.0.5",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-ckeditor": "^0.4.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.5.0",
    "robotjs": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
    "survey-angular": "^1.0.51",
    "survey-jquery": "^1.0.51",
    "surveyjs-editor": "^1.0.51",
    "xlsx": "0.12.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.52",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some more information? OS, nodejs version, used packages, command that does the error. 
Best would be a package that we could test.

Comment: @DerAlex i edit my question & i am using **npm run build** for create build

Comment: Why you have to use local ng instead of global ng build ?

Comment: The problem seems to be with npm and node and not with Angular CLI. Try upgrading Node to v 5.9.1 and re-install node_modules. I hope this will work.

Comment: @Himanshu i am already using **node version 8.9.3**

Comment: @TonyNgo i didn't get you, what it means?

Comment: What i mea is why you have to use ```node --max_old_space_size=5300 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod``` but not ```ng build --prod``` because your approach is using local angular cli

Comment: Can you pls check by removing and re-installing node_modules.

Comment: @Himanshu yes i do, but nothing happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I installed nvm, nodejs 8.9.3, npm 5.7.1 on ubuntu 18.04. First problem I encountered was, that I could not install the packages from the package.json and had to update npm to the latest version with `npm i npm@latest -g`.

The next run npm told me that there where about 33 vulnerabilities, some of them high, so that I still could not install the packages. After some `npm update, npm audit fix, npm audit fix --force` I finally could install the packages.

Then I created a new project with `npx ng new projectname` moved into that folder and did a `npm run build`. That worked.
So first I would advise you to update to the current nodejs / npm version and then update the packages and try running that build again.

Comment: i have another machine with same configuration & in that machine everything was running perfectly, why this could be happen, do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe on the other machine the dependencies have been installed some time ago and so there it still works. 
Maybe some dependencies were installed in another way or maybe on your current machine some dependencies are missing. Hard to say. But as I mentioned in my answer: Please update and reinstall your dependencies and retry your build. Hopefully it fixes your problem.

Comment: i updated my **npm version to 6.9.0** but issue still not solved

Comment: You should not only update npm, but also the nodejs version and your project dependencies defined in the package.json file.

Comment: If that still doesn't work: delete the global node_modules folder, delete the project node_modules folder, reinstall the updated dependencies and then try to run your project.